# Error: Failed to fetch RSC payload. Falling back to browser navigation

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router

I made a search form that redirects the user to the page that shows the results of his search. When I click the search button, this error occurs
`Failed to fetch RSC payload. Falling back to browser navigation. TypeError: Failed to fetch at fetchServerResponse (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/router-reducer/fetch-server-response.js:51:27) at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:282:64) at renderWithHooks (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:10697:18) at mountIndeterminateComponent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15735:13) at beginWork$1 (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17310:16) at beginWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25675:14) at performUnitOfWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24526:12) at workLoopConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24512:5) at renderRootConcurrent (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24468:9) at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23339:38) at workLoop (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:261:34) at flushWork (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:230:14) at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (webpack-internal:///(:3000/app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:534:21)`
Here is the component code that renders the form.

```
"use client";

import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation";

import SearchSvg from "@/svgs/search";

import styles from "./search.module.scss";

export default function SearchForm() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
    const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");

    function onChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        setValue(event.target.value);
    }

    function redirectToSearchResults() {
        router.push(`/cauta/${search}`);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setSearch(encodeURIComponent(value));
    }, [value]);

    return (
        <form className={styles.searchForm}>
            <input
                type="search"
                value={value}
                onChange={onChange}
                className={styles.searchInput}
                placeholder="Caută..."
            />
            <button
                className={styles.searchButton}
                onClick={redirectToSearchResults}
            >
                <SearchSvg />
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

I tried to encode the value that is passed, but still not working. What could be the problem?

Comment: perhabs somthing related to the form submit default behavior try to add event.preventDefault() to redirectToSearchResults function just like this : function redirectToSearchResults(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) { event.preventDefault(); ... } if not work try to use setSearch(encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(value)));

Comment: @Christa event.preventDefault(); did the job. Thanks!

Comment: happy to help... then i leave a answer to marke the thread solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue related to the form submit default behavior try to add **event.preventDefault()** to **redirectToSearchResults** function just like this :

```
function redirectToSearchResults(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    router.push(`/cauta/${search}`);
}
```

Comment: event.preventDefault(); did the job. Thanks!